# $ {L}_{0} $ Pseudo Norm Minimization in Compressive Sensing

Tags: compressive-sensing, optimization

I have recently taken up studying compressive sensing related papers. Some things are not very clear to me or may be I am not able to visualize the scenario as is said. Like how $l_0$ norm minimization is NP hard? Can somebody explain with an example (step by step example may be?) of a matrix and vector for an equation $y=Ax$, how $l_0$ minimization of the same can be NP hard?

Comment: Because it's equivalent to _subset selection_ problem, which is an NP Hard combinatorial optimization problem. There's more information on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_approximation)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the solution for a sparse recovery problem is given by: 
$$\text{min} ||x||_0$$
                    $$\text{s.t} \hspace{2mm}  y = Ax$$

The definition of $||x||_0$ is no. of non-zero entries in $x$. This is also called the sparsity of the vector.

i.e., we are asking for the sparsest solution $x$, that satisfies $y = Ax$.

Consider the simplest case where $x$ is 1-sparse but you don't know the location of that non-zero entry. In such a case, we have $\binom{N} {1}$ possibilities for a 1-sparse vector and to find the solution we have to examine the values of all the $\binom{N} {1}$ possibilities for finding the unique minimizer. 
Similarly, if you are told that $x$ is $k$-sparse, you need to search $\binom{N} {k}$ possibilities. 
i.e., the algorithm grows as $\binom{N}{k}$ with increase in $k$. Since $k$ is not known a priori, you have to check for all the $N$ possible values of $k$.

Hence, the complexity of the algorithm is $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^N \binom{N}{i}$. This is called as NP hard problem which is an acronym for Non-polynomial time complexity.

Comment: Could you add some Latex formatting for improved readability?

Comment: [And this is how to do it](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Thanx a lot. A clear explanation.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. Nice answer: +1

Comment: That's definitely not valid proof.
Base on his logic, given a list of numbers, and a check algorithm gives whether a list is sorted or not. We need N! times of checking, hence sorting is NP-hard?